# Is there a way to get pending comments/posts from wordpress api?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to get pending comments/posts form wordpress API.
When i type this http://testWeb/wp-json/wp/v2/comments its returning only published items. Is there a way to get pending items? What i am trying to do is to change from pending to published in my app.

Edit:
I am authenticated 
I have added to functions.php of wordpress following code:

```php
wp_enqueue_script('custom_js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', NULL, 1.0, true);
    wp_localize_script('custom_js', 'magicalData',array(
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    ));
```

And in my custom.js i have:

```
fetch("http://localhost/testWeb/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?status=pending", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "X-WP-Nonce": magicalData.nonce  //authorization 
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));  // t
```

and i still get nothing(empty object although i have one pending comment in wordpress panel)

Comment: Have you tried /comments?status=pending

Comment: No it is not working.W hen i query: /comments?status=pending   I get this response:
{
"code": "rest_forbidden_param",
"message": "Query parameter not permitted: status",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
}

Comment: status is "hold" not "pending"

Answer (score 1):

You have to be authenticated to accesses pending comments

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/

Answer (score 1):

first setup an application password for a given user.  Edit user to do this

then use this call where USERNAME is the users username, not the application name

$ curl  --user "USERNAME:APPLICATION_PASSWORD"  https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?status=hold